# Laravel Eloquent choosing which model to find

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Player model that has homeAddress which has homeAddressPhoto, linked by foreign key.

I could get the list of home address photos by calling this:

```
Player::find($player_id)->homeAddress->homeAddressPhoto;
```

Now I want to find the photos by homeAddressPhoto id, but the code below finds the photo by homeAddress id.

```
Player::find($player_id)->homeAddress->homeAddressPhoto()->where('id',$photo_id)->first();
```

How should I write the `where` part to get the id from homeAddressPhoto instead of homeAddress?

Comment: show your models

Comment: when you have `$photo_id` then you can try `$photo = HomeAddressPhoto::with('homeAddress', 'homeAddress.player')->where('id', $photo_id)->first();` assuming you have belongsTo relation in `HomeAddressPhoto` and `HomeAddress`. It is more efficient way

Comment: This is the better solution, the accepted answer would execute 5 separate queries, where this would be 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Player::find($player_id)->homeAddress->homeAddressPhoto->where('id',$photo_id)->first();
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wrote above, it finds id of homeAddress instead of homeAddressPhoto which I wanted

Comment: wait this is correct, I failed to see the lack of (), it works now, thanks

Comment: For some reason now I can use homeAddressPhoto() instead of homeAddressPhoto, probably there is a typo I was missing (I made up mock query just to ask here)